# Raspberry Pi MJPEG video stream - start application at reboot

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, mjpeg

I am making a MJPEG video stream using Raspberry Pi with dedicated Pi Camera. For this I am using jpeg libraries and the following web application found on [Github](https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer). The use is pretty straightforward, you just type `cd mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental` and then `./mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w ./www" -i "input_raspicam.so"`. However, I would like to make it run on every reboot, so that the camera is "maintenance free".

I researched that I need to put the path and the executable file in the `/etc/rc.local`. Nevertheless, when I put the path (`mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w ./www" -i "input_raspicam.so"`) to this executable file, it did not work at all. I  tried to run the stream as one command in the Terminal, it did not work either. I also tried to set up a variable PATH in `.bashrc` in order to access it from `/etc/rc.local`, but it also did not want to work.

I suspect it might have something to do with command `./mjpg_streamer`needing some input for it to work (`-o "output_http.so -w ./www" -i "input_raspicam.so"`)

Do you have any idea how to start it with every reboot?

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: try to put full path of mjpeg-streamer in your rc.local, simply go to directory with executible file , type "pwd" and in your rc.local add it as "result of pwd"/mjpeg-streamer -o ....

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and time
I tried it, and I put it into the Terminal just to check if it would work, and that is what I got.
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /home/pi/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w ./www" -i "input_raspicam.so"
MJPG Streamer Version.: 2.0
ERROR: could not find input plugin
       Perhaps you want to adjust the search path with:
       # export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/plugin/folder
       dlopen: input_raspicam.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
So I doubt it will work in `/etc/rc.local`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have solved similar issue for my rpi and jpeg streamer as following.

1. create a shell script in /home/pi

   touch /home/pi/mjpg-streamer.sh
2. edit that shell script and add this content

   #!/bin/bash

   cd  /home/pi/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/

   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.

   ./mjpg_strea‌​mer -o "output_http.so -w ./www" -i "input_raspicam.so"
3. make sure new shell script has execution rights
4. add that shell script to your /etc/rc.local